Error Ruby with Remix Integration with Error coming from `bundle install`
I hope you are doing well.
I am using Remix Shopify implementation with App Extension. After I made the app extension which is working well. But when I run Shopify app dev with trycloudflare tunnel it run for a while, then throw me this error.
› Press d │ toggle development store preview: ✔ on
› Press g │ open GraphiQL (Admin API) in your browser
› Press p │ preview in your browser
› Press q │ quit

Shutting down dev because of an error ...

── external error ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

Error coming from `bundle install`

Command failed with exit code 17: bundle install
Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from  due to underlying error <IO::TimeoutError: Failed to open TCP connection to rubygems.org:443 (Blocking        
operation timed out!) (.4.8.gz)>
Retrying fetcher due to error (3/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from due to underlying error <IO::TimeoutError: Failed to open TCP connection to rubygems.org:443 (Blocking        
operation timed out!) (.4.8.gz)>
Retrying fetcher due to error (4/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/ due to underlying error <IO::TimeoutError: Failed to open TCP connection to rubygems.org:443 (Blocking        
operation timed out!) (.4.8.gz)>
Could not fetch specs from due to underlying error
<IO::TimeoutError: Failed to open TCP connection to rubygems.org:443 (Blocking
operation timed out!) (.4.8.gz)>
Fetching source index from 

I run shopify app deploy to check if there is error from the extension and it was working perfectly.
But the shopify app dev works well for couple of minutes then suddenly shows me bundle install error.

https://prnt.sc/wxh6l7BjRAT3

I just reinstall the ruby toolkit again but with old version and the problem fixed. Thanks!

I found the solution in another Stack Overflow post. Here are the steps I followed:

Uninstall Ruby: Remove Ruby through the Windows "Programs and Features" section.
Delete Folders: Delete all Ruby and MSYS folders from the C drive.
Install Ruby+Devkit: Install but with this version Ruby+Devkit 3.1.2-1 (x64).
Update Bundler: After running the command, update Bundler by executing gem install bundler.

Note: It was not proxy problem or router problem for me.
